# Firebase storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to upload images into firebase storage, and fyi my app is under firebase phone number Auth registration. And here is my code for uploading images:

```
@IBAction func addBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        imageView.image = selectedImage
    }

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("test01.png")


    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!) {

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }


        }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("canceled picker")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But every time after I compiled, I got this error code:

> User does not have permission to access gs://cal-dev.appspot.com/profile_images/test01.png." UserInfo={object=profile_images/test01.png, ResponseBody={
>     "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
>     }

Comment: By default, storage requires Firebase authentication, so if you're authenticated you will have access to storage. I would say you're not authenticated. Add a *print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)* just before your *if let uploadData* function call and see if it prints a uid. If not, you're not authenticated. The rules for storage can be [customized](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) as well so you may also want to investigate them through the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given read and write access in your firebase console? It seems that you are not authorized to write data to firebase..

Comment: I can write to database, but not storage